# When I push refresh, I want to sustain what my data was in the screen. react useffect localstorage

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I'm cloning the movie app with React. and I'm trying to save my data to localStorage.

I know these things theoretically.
useEffect, localStorage.getItem, setItem, Json.Stringify, Json.Parse.

But for me, When it comes to using those with fetching data,
adapting this theory to my app is quite difficult.
How can I go further from this?

when I open the browser, there is an empty array prettily.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ho2bs.jpg)

and When I input harry, potter,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWQAa.jpg)
in localStorage, there is data what it was used to be(Spiderman is a first thing as you can see)

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Movie from "./components/Movie";
import "./App.css";
const FEATURED_API =
  "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sory_by=popularity.desc&api_key=31e8f214a4d938e0dd77c786d722a638&page=1";

const SEARCH_API =
  "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=31e8f214a4d938e0dd77c786d722a638&query=";

function App() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem("watched")
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("watched"))
      : []
  );
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const handleOnchange = (e) => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleOnsubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    getMovies(SEARCH_API + searchTerm);
    console.log("handleOnsubmit에서의 movies는 뭘까? : ", movies.results);
    setSearchTerm("");
  };




  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("딱 한번 실행!!!");
    getMovies(FEATURED_API);
  }, []);

  const getMovies = (API) => {
    const fetchMovie = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      const moviesResp = await fetch(API);
      const movieR = await moviesResp.json();
      setLoading(false);
      setMovies(movieR.results); // 여기서 harry로 바꼈다고 바로 밑에줄에 적용되는게 아님.
      console.log("getmovies에서의 movies는 뭘까? : ", movies);
      localStorage.setItem("watched", JSON.stringify(movies));
    };
    fetchMovie();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("빈배열 없음 >> 여러번 시행!!!");
  }, [movies]);

  console.log("useEffect 바깥에 있는 movies : ", movies);
  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <form onSubmit={handleOnsubmit}>
          <input
            className="search"
            type="text"
            placeholder="search.."
            onChange={handleOnchange}
            value={searchTerm}
          />
          <button>Search</button>
        </form>
      </header>
      <div className="movie_container">
        <div>
          {loading ? (
            <div style={{ color: "yellow", fontSize: "50px" }}>loading...</div>
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
        </div>
        {movies?.map((movie) => (
          <Movie
            key={movie.id}
            data={movie}
            title={movie.title}
            poster_path={movie.poster_path}
            vote_average={movie.vote_average}
            overview={movie.overview}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The simplest way to solve this is to use a library. https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useLocalStorage.md

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Movie from "./components/Movie";
import "./App.css";
import { useLocalStorage } from 'react-use';
const FEATURED_API =
  "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sory_by=popularity.desc&api_key=31e8f214a4d938e0dd77c786d722a638&page=1";

const SEARCH_API =
  "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=31e8f214a4d938e0dd77c786d722a638&query=";

function App() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useLocalStorage('selectedMovie', null);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are one render behind when you console.log and set Movies to storage.  The state update won't happen until the function `getMovies` is finished executing.

You have the right idea with the useEffect, but you need to set your storage there, when it is confirmed that `movies` has updated.

It also looks like you have a function inside a function unecessarily. All it does is declare and invoke a function, so it could just be its own.

Here is a refactor with changes that should work.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Movie from "./components/Movie";
import "./App.css";
const FEATURED_API =
  "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sory_by=popularity.desc&api_key=31e8f214a4d938e0dd77c786d722a638&page=1";

const SEARCH_API =
  "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=31e8f214a4d938e0dd77c786d722a638&query=";

function App() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState(localStorage.getItem("watched") || []);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleOnchange = (e) => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleOnsubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    getMovies(SEARCH_API + searchTerm);
    console.log("handleOnsubmit에서의 movies는 뭘까? : ", movies.results);
    setSearchTerm("");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getMovies(FEATURED_API);
  }, []);

  const getMovies = async (API) => {
    setLoading(true);
    const moviesResp = await fetch(API);
    const movieR = await moviesResp.json();
    setLoading(false);
    setMovies(movieR.results);
  };

  // <------->
  // This is the important part:
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("watched", JSON.stringify(movies));
  }, [movies]);

  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <form onSubmit={handleOnsubmit}>
          <input
            className="search"
            type="text"
            placeholder="search.."
            onChange={handleOnchange}
            value={searchTerm}
          />
          <button>Search</button>
        </form>
      </header>
      <div className="movie_container">
        <div>
          {loading ? (
            <div style={{ color: "yellow", fontSize: "50px" }}>loading...</div>
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
        </div>
        {movies?.map((movie) => (
          <Movie
            key={movie.id}
            data={movie}
            title={movie.title}
            poster_path={movie.poster_path}
            vote_average={movie.vote_average}
            overview={movie.overview}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you!! I'll refer it
-in Korea with Love

Comment: Good luck, @Costar don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solves the problem so future visitors to this question will know :)